# How can I get KDevelop to recognize environment variables in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, kdevelop

I'm linking against an external library in a c++ project in KDevelop. In CMakeLists.txt, I have the following:

```
include_directories($ENV{INCLUDE_PATH})
link_directories($ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
```

When I press compile in KDevelop, it complains that it cannot find the external header files and libraries. If I change above to

```
include_directories("/home/username/path/to/.h/files")
link_directories("/home/username/path/to/.so/files")
```

the project compiles without errors. Alternatively, if I open up gnome-terminal, navigate to the project directory and type in

```
cmake .
make
```

everything compiles properly. I think the problem is therefore that cmake is unaware of the environment variables INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH when called by KDevelop. I've defined these variables in my .bashrc file. Is this a problem with running KDevelop in Ubuntu (standard gnome version)? Can I configure KDevelop to recognize environment variables sent in .bashrc?

Comment: Are you print the $ENV{INCLUDE_PATH} and $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} variables when you compile with Kdevelop? Do this to debug your cmake file.

Answer (score 1):

bashrc files are read in via interactive shells.  It's possible that you want to actually move your environment variables into your .profile file which is always read in.  Once you've made the change, log out and log back in (you may even have to go as far as restarting in some linux X11 environments).